# Xcode Path to Desktop

Tags: xcode

I know `$(SRCROOT)` can be used in Xcode as shorthand for the path of the project's root folder, but is there a shorthand for the user's desktop path? Something like `$(DSKTOP)` = `/Users/username/Desktop` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(HOME)/Desktop` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use `~/Desktop`